# Al hacer click en una etiqueta p y una etiqueta li, aparece el pipe de texto en una página web

Tags: html

Estoy desarrollando una página. Cuando hago click en una etiqueta `a` o `li` me aparece el *pipe* titilante de texto (el mismo que aparece en word o en algún input de texto). Realmente no sé cómo sacarlo y es la primera vez que sucede.

No es el estilo del cursor, ya probé esa propiedad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<header class="header">

    <div class="BtnMovile" onclick="BtnSideBar()" >
        <span class="BtnSpan" >&#9776;</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="div-a">
        <a href="#">CLICK HERE FOR QUOTE</a>
    </div>

    <div class="div-p">
        <p>— SERVING YOU SINCE ’89 —</p>
    </div>      
</header>
<!-- Fin Header-->

<!-- Inicio SideBar -->
<div class="sidebarContainer">
    <div id="sidebar" >
        <ul >
            <li class="LiSide" ><a href="#">OUR WORK  </a></li>
            <li class="LiSide1" ><a href="#">ABOUT US  </a></li>
            <li class="LiSide2" ><a href="#">MATERIAL  </a></li>
            <li class="LiSide3" ><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>               
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Me gustaría saber a qué le llamas "pipe" de texto. El cursor? De todos modos, si quieres que te ayudemos con un problema de estilo... no sería lógico dejarnos ver el estilo?? Haz un [mre] que podamos ejecutar aquí y ver qué está pasando. En el editor de SO puedes añadir snippets de código html/css/javascript, va muy bien para estos casos.

Comment: Quita las estilos CSS y nos dices, por defecto el navegador usa otro cursor para los enlaces. Luego algo en los CSS de la página esta sobre-escribiendo los estilos por defecto.